# Postgresql - there is not unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table; referencing a key from own table

Tags: postgresql, reference

I created a table (team) which has a composite primary key composed of the id, project id, and a user id. Each primary key references a key in some other table except for the id. Now I want to add a key (team_id) that references the own id of the team because i want to cater a sub team and this team_id will contain the id of the parent team.

I encountered an error: 'there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "team"'.

Am I wrong to understand that each possible combination of each of the keys in the composite primary key is the team's unique constraint?
What am I missing?

```
CREATE TABLE team (

id varchar NOT NULL,
project_id varchar NOT NULL, -- team should always have associated project
user_id varchar NOT NULL, -- team member id
team_id varchar, -- parent team id
create_date date NOT NULL,
create_time time NOT NULL,
name varchar,
description text,
PRIMARY KEY (id, project_id, user_id),
FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project (id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES person (id)
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES team (id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parent_team_id varchar,
parent_team_project_id varchar,
parent_team_user_id varchar,
foreign key (
    parent_team_id, parent_team_project_id, parent_team_user_id
) references team (id, project_id, user_id);
```

But the primary key is strange. Are you sure?